# Is there a way to call Uniface-created forms from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

We would like to call Uniface form from Delphi 2010.

Is that possible?

Comment: unfortuntely..we dont have any clue,which componenet to use also.

Comment: Do you want only to show it or do you need to control lifetime or get a response back?

Comment: We want to open form and control back to delphi

Comment: No, but apparently you could do it the other way around:  You could import ActiveX/COM type libraries built in Delphi and call them from within Uniface.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know Delphi, however uniface has a number of call in mechanisms, e.g COM, C, SOAP, etc..., so as long as Delphi can call call out via these channels, then it is feasible.